# Force injected HTML to resize in a preview div Angular-UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-bind-html

I have a preview feature in my Angular-UI modal view, inside:

```
<div class="wrapper bg-white b-b ng-binding" ng-bind-html="item.content" style="overflow:auto"></div>
```

I am currently using `style="overflow:auto"` to allow scroll bars when the injected HTML has oversized img or unwrapped text. Of course this is not the best solution. What would be a good practice to allow oversized img and unwrapped text in the injected HTML to resize to fit the parent div?

Answer (score 0):

- Normally, the text inside the div will be broken to multi lines if it has many words, so don't need to care about this. But if your content have a long word (like this: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"), it will be over-wrapped. So, in this case, you need to add `word-wrap: break-word;` to the `div`.
- And with the image, you should set the max-width of the image is 100%, and the height is auto.

So we have the CSS final like this:

```
.wrapper {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```